# Convert image o bmp to a bytes array visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i have this function that recieves a bytes image then it became the bytes into a image and save the width and the height, then i will call another function to reduce the image size i must repeat until the image size file be 1mb o less, the problem is when i call the function ImagenToByte by sending jpg as parameter, the problem is in this line "img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)"

```
Public Function comprobartamano(ByVal imagenenbytes As Byte()) As Image
   
    Dim jpgoriginal As Image = ByteToImagen(imagenenbytes)
    Dim jpg As Image

    Dim w As Int64 = jpgoriginal.Width
    Dim h As Int64 = jpgoriginal.Height
    Dim tamañoDeLaImagen As Int64
    Dim ruta As String
       
    For div As Int64 = 1 To 100
            
            Dim porcentaje As Double = (100 - div) / 100
            Dim tp As Bitmap = Reduce(jpgoriginal, w * porcentaje, h * porcentaje)
            jpg = tp
            Dim binario As Byte() = ImagenToByte(jpg)
           
            tamañoDeLaImagen = binario.Length
            If tamañoDeLaImagen < 10 ^ 6 Then
                Exit For 
            End If
    Next

    Return jpg
End Function

Public Function ImagenToByte(ByVal img As Image) As Byte()
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
    img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)
    ImagenToByte = ms.GetBuffer
End Function

Public Function ByteToImagen(ByVal b As Byte()) As Image
    MsgBox(b.Length)
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(b)
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    ByteToImagen = img
End Function



Private Function Reduce(ByVal img As Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Image
    Dim imaf As New Bitmap(width, height)
    Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)
    pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic
    pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
    Return imaf
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: `dim theImage = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom([The Image Bytes]), Image)` and  `dim imageBytes = New ImageConverter().ConvertTo([Your Image], GetType(Byte()))` -- When you draw the Image to a new Bitmap, the `RawFormat` becomes `MemoryBMP`

Comment: I.e., there's no encoder for that format.